# How to call a webservice the amount of times a foreach loop runs on page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services, foreach

I am calling audio files for letter sounds in the database.  I use a webservice, jquery and c# (foreach) code to achieve this.

In the foreach loop I am calling each letters sound in a whole word but what happens is the webservice is called once on page load thus only calling the first letter's sound from the database.  This means for the word "Hat" the audio for the letter "h" is called for all instances of the 3 letters because the webservice is only called once.

C# code:

```
string s1 = words[correctImageIndex].engWord;
List<char> ia = s1.ToList();
Random random = new Random(ia.Count);
List<int> selectedIndexes = new List<int>();                             


                         foreach (var letter in ia)
                         {
                             int index = ia.IndexOf(letter);
                             int randomNumber =random.Next(0, ia.Count);
                             while (randomNumber == index || selectedIndexes.Contains(randomNumber))
                             {
                                 randomNumber = random.Next(0, ia.Count);
                             }

                            <img onclick="LetterSound()" src="~/Image/DrawLetters?letter=@ia[randomNumber]">
                             selectedIndexes.Add(randomNumber);
                         }
```

jquery code:

```
function LetterSound() {
                var id = $("[id$=hiddenWord_id]").val();
                $.ajax({

                    url: "../../WebService.asmx/LetterSound",
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
            };
```

Webservice code:

```
public void LetterSound(int id)
    {

        using (The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_FactoryDBContext())
        {

                string s1 = db.Words.FirstOrDefault(word => word.wordID == id).engWord;
                char[] ia = s1.ToCharArray();

                foreach (char letter in ia)
                {
                    string letr = letter.ToString();
                    if (db.LetterLands.FirstOrDefault(let => let.letter == letr).letterDescAudio != null)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = db.LetterLands.FirstOrDefault(let => let.letter == letr).letterDescAudio;

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                        System.Media.SoundPlayer myPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ms);
                        myPlayer.Play();
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

How can I make sure that the webservice is called for each letter in the foreach loop?

Comment: How is $("[id$=hiddenWord_id]").val(); getting populated?  (please provide your HTML markup).